# Master password of keypass

Tags: passwords

I just downloaded keypass and launched it. But it asked me to input master password.
Well, I just used it and haven't created any password. How can I have the master password?
Please see the image below.
[image: master password]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have already created a KeePass database called `Database.kdb`. It may be left over from a previous time that you (or another user of your PC) had installed KeePass. You should be able to press `Cancel` and create a new database if you want to start over from scratch.

Comment: Can I uninstall it and clear everything left over?

Comment: @Love After you uninstall KeePass, you should be able to clear whatever is left over by deleting the configuration files. See this page for the locations of KeePass's configuration files (keep in mind that there are several locations, and the locations vary based on whether you are using KeePass 1 or 2). http://keepass.info/help/base/configuration.html

Comment: @Love Also keep in mind that this will not delete your already-existing password database(s), it will just make KeePass forget that they exist. You should still locate and delete `Database.kdb` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try unchecking the box that says "use master password and keyfile" and clicking cancel, or just click cancel.

You can then do file..new and create a new database file with a password,  or do file..open  and open an existing one.  Also, a key file is optional. It's possible to have a master password without specifying/having a key file.